# Dispatcher returns wrong content-type

Tags: aem

When I first access to any css file on my dispatcher `Content-Type` of request is `"text/hml"`.

After I do a second request to this file the request has correct `Content-Type` `"text/css"`

How to fix this problem, because akamai caches first request with wrong content type?

Seems like dispatcher returns wrong css file, and caches normal variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to add add the statement

```
ModMimeUsePathInfo
```

to Apache webserver configuration

See more at [adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2338697#9593610)